# Set headers on Orbeon Ajax request

Tags: http, get, config, orbeon

When I try to request a PDF, Orbeon call this URL:

```
xforms-server/bf4532aaf8aa2306e7c4be5f63159bfffe1e20ce/orbeon-0f68c6c7df55d5746bbb48a0c5b3ffe44523795c.css
```

And it fails.

The reason is that my security filter kills it because it doesn't have the right headers.

How can I add these headers to the call?

Comment: What headers is your security filter expecting? Why do other requests to Orbeon Forms have these headers but not those to that path?

Comment: It is expecting an UID, a header that i have made. I have added in the config that orbeon should forward some headers that the browser has. But when the orbeon calls that url it doesn't have the headers.

Comment: The Orbeon header forwarding configuration won't help here, because that's not related to what's happening between the browser and the server. Couldn't use use a cookie? Then that cookie would be sent by the browser in all cases.